# Wordpress function stops page rendering

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm new to Wordpress so please bear with me here.

I'm navigating to another page from a wordpress page with the following link:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/woffice-child-theme/page-templates/loginF.php"><img src="./wp-content/themes/woffice-child-theme/page-templates/images/signin-btn.png"></a>
```

loginF.php does load but from wherever in the page I call any wordpress function like home_url() or wp_login_form() the page stops rendering. For example, if I put home_url() in the start of the page then I get an empty page in the browser. Why is this happening? Am I somehow going out of the wordpress context? What to do?

Here is loginF.php:

```
<html>

<?php
  $redirect_url = home_url();

?>

  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wp-content/themes/woffice-child-theme/page-templates/style2.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="frontpage-content">      
      <div class="front-wrap"> 
        <br/>
        <div class="new-login-logo text-center"><img src="/wp-content/themes/woffice-child-theme/page-templates/images/new-login-logo.png"></div>
        <br/><br/>
        <div class="frontpage-fields">
          <input type="text" name="log" id="user" class="input" placeholder="Email Address">
          <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pass" class="input" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="forgot-password-new"><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></div>
        <br/>
        <div class="text-center"><a href="#"><img src="./images/captcha-image.png"></a></div>
        <br/>
        <div class="text-center new-login-space"><a href="#"><img src="/wp-content/themes/woffice-child-theme/page-templates/images/new-login-btn.png"></a></div>



      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new page template as per the WordPress standard.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: My Custom Page
 */
get_header(); ?>

<!-- Your code goes here -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

Then create a new page from WordPress back end and select your page template name (the template name is given before the header call in your template file) as template in the back end & save the page.

In the page attribute section below the publish button, we can select the page template.

[Screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtStK.png)

Last, call this new page URL in your anchor tag as `href` value instead of calling the template file.

We can get the Page URL from the page title or page slug.

```
get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'your-page-slug' ) )

get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'Your page title' ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

is this the whole page html? It should begin with

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
```

and end with

```
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Added, but situation is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign your page template to any page in Wordpress and then use the page url instead of using currently. Currently you are using wrong way. Please correct it. Also don't forget to call get_header() and get_footer() in your template.

Comment: How do I assign page template to my page?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe we can come at this another way. Your link is linking to a page template, not a URL which is a bit odd. Perhaps this is causing Wordpress to get confused and go into an infinite loop.

May I ask why you're trying to link to this? Is it for a bespoke styled login page, because there are other solutions for that.

You could change the logo on the normal Wordpress login page by placing this code in your themes functions.php

```
    // log in logo link
    add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'custom_loginlogo_url' );
      function custom_loginlogo_url($url) {
      return 'http://www.yourlink.co.uk';
    }
    // login logo
    function my_login_logo() { ?>
      <style type="text/css">
        body.login div#login h1 a {
          background-image: url(<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/logo.png);
          padding-bottom: 15px;
          height: 74px;
          width: auto;
          background-size: 60% auto;
        }
      </style>
    <?php }
    add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_logo' );
```

Then just link to www.yourdomain.co.uk/wp-admin

But, if you are going to use a custom login page, use a template file that currently works, which should open with something like this

```
    <?php /* Template Name: my-template */ ?>
```

And include  in that page. Then create a page in Wordpress admin and select the template "my-template" and link to that page's URL instead.

Comment: Yes its a custom login page. How to go about integrating it some other way?